# Magento 2: get customers associated with a company

Tags: magento-2-commerce

I need to get the customers associated with a company. I have the company ID. Is it possible to get the customers of a company?

Comment: Can you please explain your issues is some more details?

Comment: I have updated my question description. It is a very straight question of Magento commerce.

Answer (score 0):

Load company and use getSuperUserId to get company admin `$company->getSuperUserId()` . Or can get company admin using this

```
Magento\Company\Model\CompanyManagement $companyManagement;
$this->companyManagement->getAdminByCompanyId($companyId);
```

To get all users it is more complicated.

```
Magento\Company\Model\Company\Structure $structureManager
$tree = $this->structureManager->getTreeById($companyId);
```

This will load all tree structure. After that just check which method in $tree to use, there is lots of different data to get and load it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added working code in my answer.

Comment: Would be nice to receive commend for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here, Is the code working for me. Posting here for helping the community. This code will check if the customer is a company admin and then it will return an array of company users' Ids. In case someone has any query please feel free to add a comment.

```
use Magento\Company\Api\CompanyHierarchyInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Company\Api\CompanyRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Company\Api\Data\HierarchyInterface;

class example extends AbstractClass
{

   /** @var CompanyHierarchyInterface */
    protected $companyHierarchy;

    /**
     * @var CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $customerRepository;

    /**
     * @var CompanyRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $companyRepository;

    /**
     * @param CompanyHierarchyInterface $companyHierarchy
     * @param CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
     * @param CompanyRepositoryInterface $companyRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        CompanyHierarchyInterface $companyHierarchy,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        CompanyRepositoryInterface $companyRepository
    )
    {
        $this->companyHierarchy = $companyHierarchy;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->companyRepository = $companyRepository;
    }
 
 
    public function getCompanyCustomerIds($customerId)
    {
       $customerData = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
       if($customerData->getExtensionAttributes()){
            if ($customerData->getExtensionAttributes()->getCompanyAttributes()
                && $customerData->getExtensionAttributes()->getCompanyAttributes()->getCompanyId() != 0) {
                $companyId = $customerData->getExtensionAttributes()->getCompanyAttributes()->getCompanyId();
                $companyAdmin = $this->companyRepository->get($companyId)->getSuperUserId();
                if($companyAdmin == $customerData->getId()) {
                    $customerIds = [];
                    $hierarchy = $this->companyHierarchy->getCompanyHierarchy($companyId);
                    foreach ($hierarchy as $item) {
                        if ($item->getEntityType() == HierarchyInterface::TYPE_CUSTOMER) {
                            $customerIds[] = $item->getEntityId();
                        }
                    }
                   return $customerIds;
                }
            }
        }
        return $customerId;
    }
    
 }
```